# String equivalence

Tags: java, string, hex

`String s="00110001"` is a string containing the hexadecimal number `31`. What I want to know is how can I convert it to a string `String a="1"`. (since the ASCII code for `1` is `49`and `49` in hexa is `31`.)

Comment: Hexadecimal value of binary `00110001` is `31` not `21`. It can be easily calculated by splitting your data like `0011` `0001` which in hex are `3` `1`.

Comment: Wait... binary or hexadecimal?

Comment: Yeah I calculated wrong. Lemme' edit... But, how can I split it like that, then convert it?

Comment: Wait so binary->hex->decimal?

Comment: It seems that you don't need to split it. You just need to calculate decimal value (like PlasmaPower showed in his answer) and then you can cast this decimal value to `char`.

Comment: Yes. My string is not a binary number. It's a hexadecimal number written binary.

Comment: In the future, it may make questions regarding numbers in different number systems easier to understand if you use an underscore or a standard number system prefix to designate a number in a particular number system. `00110001_2 = 31_16` or `0b00110001 = 0x31`, for example, says that 00110001 in base 2 is equal to 31 in base 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String hex = "";
for(int i=0; i<=s.length() - 4; i+=4) {
    hex += Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+4), 2) + "";
}
System.out.println((char)Integer.parseInt(hex, 16));
```

Comment: @user3383062 Do you want a binary or hexadecimal string inputed?

Comment: Binary. But I would like to know for hexa, too.

Comment: @user3383062 If you want to convert binary values to decimal just use radix `2` like in `Integer.parseInt(yourBinaryString, 2)`. If you have hexadecimal value in string and you want to convert it to decimal value use radix `16`.

Comment: Maybe works? Please try this. Should parse through. split it up into groups of 4 characters, convert those from binary, look up the ascii code, add it to the `hex` string, then parse the hex string for base 16.

Comment: NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: The output should be '1' (since its ASCII is 49)

Comment: Set `hex="00110001"` and try it.

Comment: And how can I do it if I want to put my result in a new string? Can't assign char to string.

Comment: @user3383062 Do `String result = "" + (char)Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)`.

Answer (score 2):

You convert the number to decimal using the Integer.parseInt(string, radix) first.

```
int dec = Integer.parseInt(s, 2); //This will give you the value 49
System.out.println((char)dec);
```

Also, correction in your question: 00110001 is 31 in decimal